# RSync Backup Strategy for home computer does not recurse into all directories

Tags: rsync, incremental-backup, backup

I am running a Linux Mint workstation at home and I am following the backup strategy from this page: http://www.jwz.org/doc/backups.html. The destination drive is a eSata drive identical to the internal drive and my rsync command looks like this:

```
sudo rsync -vaxAX --delete --ignore-errors / /media/backup/
```

where my external eSata drive is mounted on /media/backup/. I run into a slight problem with this rsync command: rsync will not go into and recurse down the /home directory. The home/ dir is created at the destination, but it stops there. If I change my source dir from / to /home/ than everything is fine. Am I doing something wrong or is this behavior by design?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-x` tells rsync to not cross filesystem boundaries. `/home` is a separate filesystem on that machine.

Comment: That's a better explanation @Ignacio

Comment: That is correct... /home is on its own partition... obvious in hindsight...